# How to avoid two processes from running parallely

Tags: java, process, jdialog

```
if (isToCloseTab && selectedTab > -1) {                    
                if (FSView.tabs[selectedTab-1].isChanged()) {
                    String tabName = tabbedPane.getTabTitleAt(selectedTab);
                    JFrame mainFrame = FSApp.getApplication().getMainFrame();
                    savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog(mainFrame, selectedTab, tabName);
                    savefiledialog.setLocationRelativeTo(mainFrame);
                    FSApp.getApplication().show(savefiledialog);
                }
                if (closeTab) {
                    tabbedPane.removeTabAt(selectedTab);
                }
```

The above code opens a dialog box when a tab is closed. Based upon the user response of the Dialog box i decide whether the tab is to be closed or not. But the problem i am facing is that the tab closes itself before the response from the dialog box. When the dialog box appears the tab closes without waiting for the response of the dialog box. I want that when the dialog box is closed only then the tab should be closed based upon the condition. Could you please help me.
-Thanks in advance

Comment: saveFileDialog should be modal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note, "processes" have nothing to do with this. A process is a program that is running, in your case you probably have just one process.

In your case, what you need is probably a modal dialog. See constructors that take a Dialog.ModalityType argument. Then use the dialog's setVisible() method instead of show(). For modal dialogs, it will block until the user closes the dialog.

Of course, it is also depends on the context of your code. If it is executed after the tab is closed, nothing will help you. You'll need to move it somewhere else, but it is hard to say where without seeing the whole picture.